# Regex Negative lookbehind case in R

Tags: r, regex

Hey I would like to extract names from a text - my identifying pattern is that names will always start with a capital letter and there will be two or three words with a capital letter in a row. Furthermore, I account for the fact that there could be an author called "Jack Jr. Bones" - so I make the "." optional. The last case could be that there is an institution in the text with an article e.g. "the Robert Brown theater, so I would like to exclude all cases, where the two/three words with a capital letter are preceded by a "the". I do this by using a negative lookbehind:

```
test <- test <- "A beautiful day for Jack Bones ended in the Robert Brown theater"
str_extract(test, "(?<!the\\s)(([A-Z][\\w]+\\s[A-Z][\\w]+[[:punct:]]?\\s[A-Z][\\w]+)|([A-Z][\\w]+\\s[A-Z][\\w]+))")
[1] "Jack Bones"
```

But now I am facing the following problem: if a sentence starts with "The Robert Brown theater" then I will match this pattern too. I thought I can be smart and just add "(?i) in the negative look behind, but it turn out it does not work

```
test <- "The Robert Brown theater was nice, but Jack Bones did not enjoy his time there"
str_extract(test, "(?<!(?i)the\\s)(([A-Z][\\w]+\\s[A-Z][\\w]+[[:punct:]]?\\s[A-Z][\\w]+)|([A-Z][\\w]+\\s[A-Z][\\w]+))")
[1] "The Robert Brown"
```

Another idea was to just add an or condition

```
str_extract(test, "(?<!(the\\s|The\\s))(([A-Z][\\w]+\\s[A-Z][\\w]+[[:punct:]]?\\s[A-Z][\\w]+)|([A-Z][\\w]+\\s[A-Z][\\w]+))")
[1] "The Robert Brown"
```

Then I tried if it would work if a use only "The" in the negative look behind and I discovered that even this would not work

```
str_extract(test, "(?<!The\\s)(([A-Z][\\w]+\\s[A-Z][\\w]+[[:punct:]]?\\s[A-Z][\\w]+)|([A-Z][\\w]+\\s[A-Z][\\w]+))")
[1] "The Robert Brown"
```

Now I am a little bit clueless. I do not understand why the negative look behind works with "the", but fails to work if I condition on "The". I would appreciate any help and insight!

Comment: This question is ill-defined. For example, if the string is "Call Robert Brown now", how will you know to return "Robert Brown" rather than "Call Robert"? What about "It is Robert E. Brown Musuem" versus "He is Robert E. Brown Jr." or "He is Robert E. Brown Junior"? What about "He is John  Smith-Jones, the banker"? And what about "Cher is a great actress", considering that "Cher" is her full legal name. :-)

Comment: In the general case you are right. However, in my case I only work with the first paragraph of a text and there it is a feature of the data that the only upper case words without "the" in front are the authors name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I also found out why my own code fails in this example.

My pattern will already match "The Robert" and then check if there is a the or The in front, which is of course not the case. Hence, I need an additional look ahead for "The":

```
test <- "The Robert Brown theater was nice, but Jack Bones and Hover Edgar did not enjoy his time there"
str_extract(test, "(?<![Tt]he\\s)((?!The))(([A-Z][\\w]+\\s[A-Z][\\w]+[[:punct:]]?\\s[A-Z][\\w]+)|([A-Z][\\w]+\\s[A-Z][\\w]+))")
[1] "Jack Bones"
```

Trimming down the code gives:

```
str_extract(test,"(?<![Tt]he\\s)((?!The))[A-Z][\\w]+\\s[A-Z][\\w]+([[:punct:]]\\s[A-Z][\\w]+)?")
[1] "Jack Bones"
```

This solution has the additional advantage that I can stay within the framework of str_extract and I do not have to move to another function in R that allows for the Perl syntax.

Answer (score 2):

It is a variation of [**the greatest regex trick ever**](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html):

```
 match_this | or_this | (but_really_keep_this)
```

In terms of `R`, you could use the often overlooked standard regex functions with `perl = TRUE`:

```
test <- c("A beautiful day for Jack Bones ended in the Robert Brown theater",
          "The Robert Brown theater was nice, but Jack Bones did not enjoy his time there")

pattern <- "(?:[Tt]he\\s+(?:[A-Z][\\w.]*\\s*){2,3})(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?:[A-Z][\\w.]*\\s*){2,3}"

m <- gregexpr(pattern, test, perl = T)
lapply(regmatches(test, m), trimws)
```

Which yields

```
[[1]]
[1] "Jack Bones"

[[2]]
[1] "Jack Bones"
```

---

You see, the used pattern basically reads like this:

```
The/the Word1 Word2 Word3 | (Word1 Word2 Word2)
```

---

You can even shorten your code to a very unreadable one-liner (though this is not recommended):

```
lapply(regmatches(test, gregexpr(pattern, test, perl = T)), trimws)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only problem I could run into with this solution would be if in a text is written "...Jack Bones,...." -- it would not catch the name because there is no "\\s" behind it, but a comma. If I am right I could solve this by making the space "\\s" optinal with "?"?

Comment: @Methamortix: No need to change anything here - the `\s*` accounts for that. It says zero or more whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is negative lookahead. You can see it [here](https://regex101.com/r/oq4ZXt/1)

```
(?!(the\\s|The\\s))(([A-Z][\\w]+\\s[A-Z][\\w]+[[:punct:]]?\\s[A-Z][\\w]+)|([A-Z][\\w]+\\s[A-Z][\\w]+))
```

You own regex almost did the trick.

For further reading about this you can check [this](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) link

Comment: Ah ok I see it works but I am confused. "Negative Lookahead" says "Asserts that what immediately follows the current position in the string is not foo". Maybe I understand it wrong, but for me that means, that what follow my pattern should not be "the".

Comment: For a n even simpler string the negative lookahead falis to work:
````test <- "The Robert Brown theatre Bank fires Jack Bones"````
````str_extract(test, "(?!(the\\s|The\\s))(([A-Z][\\w]+\\s[A-Z][\\w]+[[:punct:]]?\\s[A-Z][\\w]+)|([A-Z][\\w]+\\s[A-Z][\\w]+))") ```` ````"Robert Brown Theatre"````